# QSplashScreen on Qt Quick 2

Tags: qt, qt5, qtquick2

I'm having trouble using QSplashScreen on a new Qt Quick 2 project. Here's the project 'main.cpp':

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPixmap pix("./test80.png");

    QSplashScreen splash(pix);

    splash.show();

    QTest::qSleep(5000);

    splash.hide();

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/teste/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app.exec();
}
```

This code compiles. When I run it, application output shows the following message: `QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget without QApplication`. So apparently QGuiApplication doesn't inherit from QApplication, so I'm stumped.

**Edit**: changing QGuiApplication to QApplication seemed to work, but I'm worried that QApplication will lack something needed by Qt Quick 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact it's the other way around: QApplication inherits from QGuiApplication. And you need the former to use widgets. :-)

Comment: So, there's no way to use QSplashScreen in a Qt Quick 2 project?

Comment: Yes: just use QApplication instead of QGuiApplication. Of course, you need to link to QtWidgets (`QT += widgets` in the .pro file). A different approach (if you don't want a widgets dependency just for a splashscreen) is doing a splashscreen in QML. I'm sure that either with QtQuick Controls (included with Qt 5.1), or just with *another* QQuickView (with the right window flags set), you can hack a QSplashScreen-like window.

Comment: So, I changed QGuiApplication to QApplication and it worked. But wouldn't it mess up with something? I mean, QGuiApplication isn't there for nothing, right?

Comment: David McDavidson: QGuiApplication is to be able to use UI (i.e. QtQuick) applications without widgets dependency. QApplication depends on QtWidgets. It won't "mess up" things, but it's questionable if a splashscreen is worth the dependency.

Comment: Frank, what would be the consequences of depending on QtWidgets? How will it affect my code?

Comment: Your code won't be affected. It's just that you will have to ship another (big) library from which you're only using something as simple as a splashscreen; and as I said, I think it's feasable to just do a splashscreen-like screen in pure QML, thus without the need to use QtWidgets.

Comment: I've made a replacement of QSplashScreen that does not depend on the widgets module: https://github.com/pedrolcl/SplashWindow